# Show selected value in dropdown after submit

Tags: php, mysql, validation, submit

hi guys i added dropdown field to form however after i submit the form if there is any error dropdown resets itself how can keep to value after validation thanks a lot for your any helps and idea
here is my code

```
<td><select id="country" name="country"  style="width:150px;">
         <option value="-1">Select</option>
     <?php
$query = "SELECT country_id, name FROM countries ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<option value=\"".$row['country_id']."\" >".$row['name']."</option>\n  ";
}
?>
</select></td>
<td><?php echo $form->error("country"); ?></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would set the default option with attribute `selected` that is tied to the current selected value.  So in this case, the option that equals the value of `$_POST['country']`:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($row['country_id'] == $_POST['country'])
        $selected = "selected=\"selected\"";
    else
        $selected = "";
    echo "<option value=\"".$row['country_id']."\" $selected>".$row['name']."</option>\n ";
}
```

Which would render as the following on the appropriate option:

```
<option value="123" selected="selected">456</option>
```